# Error when trying to runing an ssr server using inertiajs

Tags: javascript, node.js, inertiajs

I did all the step by step to run an ssr application, but without success.

config/inertia

```
export const inertia: InertiaConfig = {
  view: 'app',
  ssr: {
    enabled: true,
    autoreload: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
  },
};
```

resources/js/ssr.js

```
import { createSSRApp, h } from 'vue';
import { renderToString } from '@vue/server-renderer';
import {createInertiaApp, Link} from '@inertiajs/vue3';

export default function render(page) {
  return createInertiaApp({
    page,
    render: renderToString,
    resolve: (name) => require(`./Pages/${name}`),
    setup({ app, props, plugin }) {
      return createSSRApp({
        render: () => h(app, props),
      }).use(plugin).component('inertia-link', Link);
    },
  });
}
```

run the commands

node ace serve --watch
node ace ssr:watch

```
require() of ES Module C:\Users\Projeto\node_modules@inertiajs\vue3\dist\index.js from C:\Users\Projeto\inertia\ssr\ssr.js not supported. index.js is treated as an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which declares all .js files in that package scope as ES modules. Instead rename index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules, or change "type": "module" to "type": "commonjs" in C:\Users\Projeto\node_modules@inertiajs\vue3\package.json to treat all .js files as CommonJS (using .mjs for all ES modules instead).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must be capitalized App

```
setup({ App, props, plugin }) {
      return createSSRApp({
        render: () => h(App, props),
      }).use(plugin);
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

the issue here can be the use of `require` on the code line

```
resolve: (name) => require(`./Pages/${name}`),
```

instead use import

```
resolve: (name) => import(`./Pages/${name}`),
```

since you are already using ES modules in that file

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I'm glad for the help. The appearance problem has been fixed, but another error has occurred.  "Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module"

Comment: https://nopad.lif3.app/?gclid=Cj0KCQjwz8emBhDrARIsANNJjS5azuxICEtQX3zT81UF6yfUHDzCMr7qCpILaSz5heCimmes4w9iDK4aAnp7EALw_wcB